# Not able to read XLS salesforce reports - java.io.IOException: Can't open workbook - unsupported file type: UNKNOWN

Tags: java, salesforce, apache-poi, xlsx, xls

I want to download Sfdc Reports and extract data. We were downloading xlsx but found out that some of the columns values are truncated and only 255 characters are displayed in xlsx report.
But if we download XLS report we are getting complete data.
I tried reading XLS file with Java Apache POI using below code

```
   Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile)
```

with above initialization I am getting below error
java.io.IOException: Can't open workbook - unsupported file type: UNKNOWN
If I use HSSFWorkBook I get this error - org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x4D3C3E646165683C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

We tried different encoding options as well still we are not able to read any xls reports. file downloaded from SalesForce.

Export Screenshot from SalesForce[image]

Also if I open it using excel it shows below warning but it shows the data after clicking on YES
[image]

When I open the file using notepad++ it looks like this[image]

Comment: read 0x4D3C3E646165683C: The content of the file seems to be HTML instead of binary XLS. Those first bytes are "<head><M" stored in big endian hex.

Comment: Are you sure you really downloaded the Excel file from SalesForce? As per @AxelRichter's observation, it looks like you may have saved the HTML page that hosts the link to the file instead...

Comment: I download from export option, Let me update the screenshots

Comment: @AxelRichter - I have updated the screenshots, I opened that file in notepad and it looks like HTML(screenshot updated),Can you let me know how I can read this file

Comment: @Nitin Rathod; "how I can read this file": Not possible using Apache POI. The file content is "fake XLS". That is HTML declared as XLS. Excel is tolerant enough to read such files after warning. But Apache POI can only read real binary XLS.